# Libgdx how to detect swipe over actor

Tags: libgdx

I would like to know how to detect that an actor has been swiped over? I know that i have to use the gesture detector but I don't know how to register that the swipe trajectory has intersected the actor bounds. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ActorGestureListener](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ActorGestureListener.html). Usage example:

```
Actor actor = new Actor();
actor.addListener(new ActorGestureListener() {
    public void fling (InputEvent event, float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
            System.out.println("swipe!! " + velocityX + ", " + velocityY);
    }
});
```